# Salesforce Visualforce (VFP) Page Renders as PDF but when Downloaded, the data will not show in the table

Tags: pdf, salesforce, render, visualforce

I set up a VFP that pulls in a checkable list of records from a list view. It renders properly and shows the records. But for some reason when I download the page and open it in Adobe or the web it’s not showing the data in the table.

APEX CODE:

```
global virtual with sharing class LoadsBatchMill_V2 {
    global List<FR__Load__c> loadList {get;set;}
    global String renderAs { get; set; }
    global ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;
    global Set<Id> loadIds = new Set<Id>();

    global LoadsBatchMill_V2(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController){
        this.standardController = standardController;
        loadList = new List<FR__Load__c>();
        for (FR__Load__c load : (List<FR__Load__c>)standardController.getSelected()){ 
        loadIds.add(load.Id);
        }
        loadList = [SELECT Name, Pickup_By__c, Quantity__c, FR__Commodity__c, E_BOL_Link__c FROM FR__Load__c WHERE ID IN: loadIds];}
    }
```

VISUALFORCE PAGE CODE:

```
<apex:page standardController="FR__Load__c" extensions="LoadsBatchMill_V2" recordSetVar="Loads" sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false" renderAs="PDF">
   <head>
        <style>
        
            body { 
                font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; 
            }
            blackline { 
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }
            table { 
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
            }
            td,th{
                <!--border: 1px solid #8f8f8f;-->
                border: 1px solid #c7cdd4;
                padding: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <div style="body; font-size: .85em">
            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.FR}" width="120"/> <br /><br /><br />

    <apex:pageBlock rendered="true">
        <apex:pageBlockTable width="100%" align="center" style="border: none; vertical-align: bottom;" value="{!loadList}" var="L">
            <apex:column value="{!L.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!L.Pickup_By__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!L.Quantity__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!L.FR__Commodity__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Comment out the `<apex:image url="{!$Resource.FR}"`. Images in static resources generally don't display nice in PDF, you'd need a Document record with "externally available image" ticked. But it shouldn't cause the whole thing to fail, just render as broken icon.
2. `<apex:pageBlockTable>` renders poorly in PDFs because it comes with bunch of JavaScript that doesn't run. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_component_behavior.htm Printing nice PDFs is bit of an art, see if you can use `<apex:repeat>` and manually craft the `<table><tr><td>...`. See if you can steal some ideas from my answer to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/194167/799
3. For debugging (and faster rendering) you can remove `renderAs="PDF"` from your page and add it when you're relatively happy with the output.

Comment: The static resource image is displaying properly. The issue is with the data not displaying in the apex:pageblock and the last column not allowing the Hyperlink to be clicked when the PDF is downloaded from the PDF preview screen. I'm trying to render the PDF link from a field because that was the only way I knew to do it. The formula field link is: HYPERLINK('http://customdomainnamehere.force.com/sol/solWithSignature?id='+Id, "View BOL", "_blank")

Comment: What's the link to, "digital experience" (formerly known as customer/partner communities)? Try with something like `<apex:column headerValue="View"><a href="https://customdomainnamehere.force.com/sol/solWithSignature?id={!L.Id}">Link</a></apex:column>`